Same p-value of overall model and binary predictor level 2 versus Intercept (lm function in R)
I have a response variable PC1 (it is PCA scores for a bunch of observations). I have a response variable category with two levels (HT and MT), which basically classifies the observations in 2 groups. I use lm function in R to find out the r-squared and the difference in the two levels of category. See the results of the function call:
Call:
lm(formula = PC1 ~ category, data = dims)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.02263 -0.53187 -0.02024  0.60599  2.30848 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.10100    0.08248   1.225   0.2217  
categoryMT  -0.20271    0.11684  -1.735   0.0838 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9966 on 289 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01031,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.006883 
F-statistic:  3.01 on 1 and 289 DF,  p-value: 0.08382

The p-value for categoryMT (0.0838) is the same as the p-value shown in the last line (0.08382). Why both values are the same? Would this be the case if category had three levels? Lastly, for this particular case can I simply report the F statistic, degrees of freedom, and the p-value given for the F statistic to show the categoryMT is not significantly different from Intercept (categoryHT)?

What specifically is the "the overall model"??  You use "MT" as if it were the name of a variable but you introduce it as one level of a single (unnamed) variable.  These issues make your question difficult to understand and might cause it to be understood in different ways by different readers.  Please edit your post to clarify what you're trying to ask.

This is an elementary result. The F-test at the bottom compares all the model specified covariates against a "null" model - one which includes only an intercept. The t-test at the top, however, considers only the contribution of a single covariate by way of the Wald statistic. Seeing that you only have one non-trivial covariate (categoryMT) they provide identical inference.
